# Getting the "too many values to unpack (expected 2)" error when evaluating a model

Tags: python, valueerror

I keep getting the error "too many values to unpack (expected 2)" whenever I try to evaluate my model. I have no clue what is causing this error and how to fix it. Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Conv3D(input_shape=(44,64,64,1), filters=8, kernel_size=3, 
                      strides=2, activation='relu', name='Conv1'),
  keras.layers.Flatten(),
  keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name='Softmax')
  ])
model.summary()

batch_size = 16
testing = False
epochs = 3

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(), 'accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images,
          train_labels,
          validation_data=(test_images, test_labels),
          epochs=epochs)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels) #This is where I am getting the error
print('\nTest accuracy: {}'.format(test_acc))
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

Note: Thanks to Tuqay for pointing out the issue.

Comment: `model.evaluate` returns a list with length of more than 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use a catch-all placeholder while unpacking. See example behavior below.

```
test_loss, test_acc, *is_anything_else_being_returned = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels) #This is where I am getting the error

>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> b,c,*d = a
>>> b
1
>>> c
2
>>> d
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>>
```